# HttpClient Post to ApacheServer (Debian)

Tags: c#, wpf, http, encoding, character-encoding

I have a c# WPF application which sends a POST request to an php site.
The site is hosted on an apache server which runs on Debian.

My problem is sending chars like äöüß, those aren't encoded right i suppose because if i open the php site directly there aren't those chars but symbols.

I already tried setting charset to utf-8.
Did i forget something?

Here's some code:

```
var url = "http://internalServer/input.php"
using (var client = await Login())
        {
            if (client == null) return false;

            foreach (var item in day.Workitems)
            {
                if (item.IsSynced) continue;

                try
                {
                    var syncedText = item.Description;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Notes))
                    {
                        foreach (var line in item.Notes.Split(new [] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(syncedText)) syncedText += ", ";
                            syncedText += line;
                        }
                    }

                    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Ticket", item.Nr),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Text", syncedText)
                    });

                    await DoRequest(client, url, content);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private async Task<string> DoRequest(HttpClient client, string url, HttpContent content = null)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(content == null ? HttpMethod.Get : HttpMethod.Post, url);

        if (content != null)
        {
            request.Content = content;
        }

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#: try encoding with base64. see [.netfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9SV5bI)

```
using System;               
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] encbuff = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("äöüß");
        string syncedText = Convert.ToBase64String(encbuff);
        Console.WriteLine(syncedText); // you get "w6TDtsO8w58="    
    }
}
```

In PHP: enforcing utf-8

```
<?php
    $str = $_REQUEST['Text']; // "w6TDtsO8w58="
    echo base64_decode($str); // you get "äöüß"
?>
```

If you don't want to change anything in C# side, then try this

```
<?php 
    // you may want to detect the encoding of the request string
    $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($str,"UTF-8,ISO-8859-1,ISO-8859-2,windows-1250");
    if( $encoding == "UTF-8" ) {
        echo utf8_decode($str);
        // do something ...
    }
    else {
        // if encoded with charset windows-1250, ISO-8859-2, ISO-8859-1
        // e.g, $str = "Zusammenf%FChrung"; // %FC = ü
        echo mb_convert_encoding(urldecode($str), "utf-8", "ISO-8859-2");
        // you get "Zusammenführung" as utf-8
    }
?>
```

OR

```
<?php    
    /* 
     * if your encoding is limited to a specific charset,
     * you shall try changing php header as below.
     */
    header('Content-Type: charset=ISO-8859-2');
    echo urldecode("Zusammenf%FChrung");
    // Note: insert the header() function before generating any content
?>
```

Comment: Because i can't test it here (the server only accessible within it's network) i have to ask, would following code do the trick?  `var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Ticket", item.Nr),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Text", Convert.ToBase64String(syncedText))
                    });`

Comment: Note: `System.Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])` , you have to convert `syncedText` to byte[] before converting it to base64String, otherwise, it will throw invalid argument exception.

Comment: Maybe this helps, i sniffed the POST that's being made by the Browser. That's one param string: `Zusammenf%FChrung`, therefore `%FC` has to be ü. But what encoding is this and how can i send it like that with my HttpClient?

Comment: It can be of `windows-1250, ISO-8859-2, ISO-8859-1`. Try this in php `echo mb_convert_encoding(urldecode("%FC"), "utf-8", "ISO-8859-2");`

Comment: Thanks already! So `ISO-8859-2` seems to be the encoding, the last question would be would `content.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "ISO-8859-2"` work? I can test it only tomorrow.

Comment: you shall detect the encoding of the request using `mb_detect_encoding` function in PHP then generate the desired response. ref:http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101536/discussion-between-thoor-and-kolunar).